# Undefined references

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I want to make reference on my next formula

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:model}
f = \sigma_k\circ\underset{1\times1}{\wm_k^\mathsf{T}\sigmab_{k-1}}\circ\w_{k-1}\sigmab_{k-2}\circ\dots\circ\underset{n_2 \times 1}{\w_2\sigmab_1}\circ\underset{n_1 \times n}{\w_1}\underset{n \times 1}{\x}.
\end{equation}
```

in next way

```
\eqref{eq:model}
```

But only ?? are shown.

P.S. I have checked some solutions from here but they all didn't help.

UPD. I founded out that problem in hyperref package. it removed allows to make working references. But how should I fix it if I need this package?

UPD2 Due to  Marijn's comment I've tried to make simple example.
This code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{autonum}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:model}
f = \mathbf{w}^T\lambda
\end{equation}

this is ref \eqref{eq:model}
\end{document}
```

works fine. But added `\usepackage{hyperref}` breaks it and I get ?? again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you run LaTeX two times? The first time it generates the label, the second time it uses the label to print the reference number in the text. If this is not the issue, then do you get any errors or warnings? Anything in the log file? If not, then you should make a small but complete example of code that can be executed and shows the problem, and add that to your question.

Comment: Yes, I complied it many times. I get warning that there is undefined reference in this line.

Comment: You have posted a lot of code but no code that can allow anyone to debug yur problem. Most of the list of packages are unrelated to your question. Please post a small self contained document that shows the problem, with `\ref{eq:mode}` not showing the number. But if you are using a language package that makes `:` active try not using colons in labels.

Comment: Regarding your update: please make a small example so we can reproduce the problem. This would be very useful to help you further. Start with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{hyperref}\begin{document}\begin{equation} \label{eq:myeq}a=b \end{equation}Reference:\ref{eq:myeq}\end{document}`. Compile and check if it works. Then, start adding other packages. Compile after each package that you add. When the problem appears, then remove all packages that were not related. Then post your minimal example here.

Comment: `hyperref` and `autonum` don't really play well with each other. IIRC one solution is to use `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}` but I seem to remember that there are some drawbacks to that.

Comment: You speculate, "I founded out that problem in `hyperref` package." No, that's *not* the source of the problem. The problem, rather, lies in the use of the `autonum` package, which is not all that robust. Real quick: Why do you load this package?

Comment: I use this package for numerating only the formula which have references on it in order to simplify article